# Clip bathymetry raster file from vector mask layer its not working in QGIS 3.4.3

Tags: raster, clip, extract-by-mask, qgis-3

I'm trying to extract bathymetry of Mediterranean Sea raster GeoTIFF file (downloaded from https://www.bodc.ac.uk/data/hosted_data_systems/gebco_gridded_bathymetry_data/gebco_30_second_grid/) from bathymetry (vector mask layer) downloaded from Natural Earth data.

After I selected bathymetry depth 0 at query builder of the vector layer, used Raster > Extraction > Clip raster by mask layer, but the area of elevation its grayed and not deleted.

[image]

I tried save as both layers raster and vector with same CRS WGS 84 and still the same result. 
After save as the raster GeoTIFF (GEBCO2014_-12.3),(Gebco 4326 GeoTIFF) in CRS WGS 84 used again Raster > Extraction > Clip raster by mask layer. [image]

How can i resolve this ?

Comment: Ensure that your raster data and your vector data share the same coordinate reference system before executing the clip. Some tools fail when this is not the case.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to add details requested in comments. It's not fair to those who would help to force them to need to sift through comments for critical information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the QGIS GDAL process it is impossible to clip the raster INT16 GeoTIFF downloaded from [GEBCO_2014 Grid (30 arc-second interval)](https://www.gebco.net/data_and_products/gridded_bathymetry_data/) so i downloaded the **SCP plugin** and used **Band set > Preprocessing > Clip multiple rasters**. The result was fine the raster was clipped well by the polygon layer bathymetry level 0 but had some issues at value 1000 (missing pixels at depth 1000)

[image].

So i thought that the problem could be at INT16 GeoTIFF file type and downloaded from [GEBCO_2014 Grid (30 arc-second interval)](https://www.gebco.net/data_and_products/gridded_bathymetry_data/) ESRI ASCII and Save as GeoTIFF with the same projection of bathymetry polygon layer. After reopen the raster GeoTIFF used **Raster > Extraction > Clip raster by mask layer** and was clipped as i wanted without any issues.

[image]